# How to update Meteor array element inside a document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor Mongo document as shown below

```
{
    "_id" : "zFndWBZTvZPgSKXHP",
    "activityId" : "aRDABihAYFoAW7jbC",
    "activityTitle" : "Test Mongo Document",
    "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "b1@gmail.com",
            "type" : "free"
        },
                {
            "id" : "JqKvymryNaCjjKrAR",
            "type" : "free"
        },
    ],
}
```

I want to update a specific array element's email with custom generated id using Meteor query something like the below.

for instance, I want to update the document 
if  `'users.id' == "b1@gmail.com"` then update it to `users.id = 'SomeIDXXX'`

So updated document should looks like below.

```
{
    "_id" : "zFndWBZTvZPgSKXHP",
    "activityId" : "aRDABihAYFoAW7jbC",
    "activityTitle" : "Test Mongo Document",
    "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "SomeIDXXX",
            "type" : "free"
        },
        {
            "id" : "JqKvymryNaCjjKrAR",
            "type" : "free"
        },

    ],
}
```

I have tried the below but didnt work.

```
 Divisions.update(
      { activityId: activityId, "users.id": emailId },
      { $set: { "users": { id: _id } } }
    );
```

Can someone help me with the relevant Meteor query ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is actually almost right except for a small part where we want to identify the element to be updated by its index.

```
Divisions.update({
"activityId": "aRDABihAYFoAW7jbC",
 "users.id": "b1@gmail.com"
}, {
$set: {"users.$.id": "b2@gmail.com"}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need the arrayFilters option.

```
Divisions.update(
  { activityId: activityId },
  { $set: { "users.$[elem].id": "SomeIDXXX" } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.id": "b1@gmail.com" } ], multi: true }
);
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [$push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) instead of $set.

`{ $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }`

Comment: This adds a new object to the array. Syam is asking how to update an existing object in the array.

Comment: Yes @BartS said is right. I want to update existing element.